# How can one get the value of a text input using Selenium with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver

Using [Selenium for .NET](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html), how can I get the current value from a html input?

It's possible to `.GetAttribute()` to get the `value` attribute but this is the html attribute rather than the current value entered into the text box; an approach similar to jQuery's `.val()` rather than jQuery's `.attr()`.

Comment: "Selenium for .NET" link is broken (http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html): 
404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`Element.Text` didn't work for me.  I used `element.GetAttribute("value")`

Check out this Q&A
[Setting input textbox text and then retrieving it in Specflow & Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016888/setting-input-textbox-text-and-then-retrieving-it-in-specflow-selenium)