# Setting input textbox text and then retrieving it in Specflow & Selenium

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver, specflow

Could someone explain to me why in the following .Net Specflow code if my textboxElement's text is empty, then I send keys to it, why is text still empty? (when on screen the textbox's text changes):

```
textboxElement.SendKeys("John Smith");
var text = textboxElement.Text;
// text == ""
```

Is it not possible to "refresh" the value of an element? (or have I just missed something really obvious :-))

Comment: You'll want to use `textBoxElement.GetAttribute("value");`. It's an `input` element. `input` elements don't usually store their **displayed** text like other elements, but rather in their `value` properties.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since it's an `input` element, you'll need to get it's `value` property as opposed to it's `text`.

So:

```
textBoxElement.GetAttribute("value");
```