# How can I get the id and value of an item using Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to retrieve for each question i want to answer I want to know the ID and the value.

I have written the following code but I dont know how to finish it so that it gives me the ID and the value:

```
    private IWebElement GetAnswerElement(int questionNumber, int answerNumber)
    {
        return BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format("//div[@id = 'client-assessment']/div/div/label", questionNumber, answerNumber)));
    }
```

The code looks like this:

```
<div id="client-assessment" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="question">
        <label class="question">
            Here is my question1
        </label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input id="xxx" name="xxx" onchange="UpdateAssessment()" 
        </div>
```

code continues with more questions

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Please explain in detail the exact issue you are facing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one get the value of a text input using Selenium with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121302/how-can-one-get-the-value-of-a-text-input-using-selenium-with-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the `id` and `value` attribute of the `input` element you can do the following.

```
private IWebElement GetAnswerElement()
{
    var xpath = "//div[@id='client-assessment']/div/div/label/input";
    return BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
}

var element = GetAnswerElement()
var id = element.GetAttribute("id");
var value = element.GetAttribute("value");
```

Note that I've changed the xpath that it selects the `input` element.

---

If you directly want to use xpath to check for the two attributes you can do the following.

```
private IWebElement GetAnswerElement(string questionText, string answerText)
{
    var xpath = String.Format(
                    "//div[@id='client-assessment']/div/div/label/input[@id='{0}'][@value='{1}']", 
                    questionText, 
                    answerText);
    return BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
}

var element = GetAnswerElement(
                  "Product_Contractor_ClientAssessment_Question06",
                  "Answer1");
```

Or if you only want to check for the number at the end of the string.

```
private IWebElement GetAnswerElement(int questionNumber, int answerNumber)
{
    var xpath = String.Format(
                    "//div[@id='client-assessment']/div/div/label/input[ends-with(@id, '{0}')][ends-with(@value, '{1}')]", 
                    questionNumber.ToString("00"), 
                    answerNumber.ToString("0"));
    return BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
}

var element = GetAnswerElement(6, 1);
```

Note that I format the `questionNumber` value with `00`. I do this to prevent the number 66 from beeing matched when 6 is given.

Comment: Thanks.

In the past I did something like:

        private IWebElement NewCountryWithinDropdown(string dutchCountryName)
        {
            return 
                BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//ul/li/a/span[text()='{0}']", dutchCountryName)));                                                                           
        }

(dont mind the xpath. Is that also possible in this case that you make use of {0} and {1} to retrieve the ID and the value?

Comment: @xxx2017 You can only check for specific attributes like this but not retrieve them. To get them you have to do it like I described in my answer.

Comment: If I only want to check for the specific attributes how do I do that? Because I remember from previous assignments I should do something with {0} and [1}

Comment: @xxx2017 I've added a little more detail

Comment: Thanks for your help. But what I am looking for is the following:
I have 10 questions and each question has 3 possible answers. As I dont want to have 30 elements. I want to be able to say I want to answer question 1 with answer 3. Select that element for me.

So that in my public void I can make a var that selects that element, go to that element and than do a click on it.

Comment: @xxx2017 Isn't this what my last example does?