# How can I get the value from a <input> to use on an automated test using c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this piece of HTML that I want to extract the "IMPORTANT STUFF"  text.

```
<input data-lock="2" data-val="true" data-val-required="Required" id="stuff" name="stuff" placeholder="blablabla" type="text" value="IMPORTANT STUFF" class="">
```

mapping:

```
public By stuffmapping = By.Id("stuff");
```

Using .Text, my string is always empty.

```
IWebDriver driver;
string importantstuff = driver.FindElement(map.stuffmapping).Text;
```

Is there any other way to get the "IMPORTANT STUFF"?

Comment: What is `map.AccountName`?  Should that be `stuffmapping`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one get the value of a text input using Selenium with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121302/how-can-one-get-the-value-of-a-text-input-using-selenium-with-c)

Answer (score 4):

The `Text` value won't work because it isn't the actual text of the control. The thing you see is actually the value of an attribute given to the element. This is usually the case for `input` controls.

So you'll want something like:

```
driver.FindElement(sutffMapping).GetAttribute("value");
```

The reason for this is that the text shown on screen is coming from the `value` attribute of the `input` control.