# How does Selenium get the hiding text from knockout's data-bind like data-bind="textInput: overridePassword, enable: false"

Tags: c#, selenium

I am creating `selenium` automation for our UI testing, and I tried to generate a random password for a user. How does `selenium 3` `WebDriver` based on `C#` get the text of `html5` knockout data-bind? I am using `selenium 3` framework based on `C#` and `Visual Studio 2019`

```
<input id="txtGeneratedPassword" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: overridePassword, enable: false" title="" disabled="">
```

The following is the part of my code:

```
IWebElement passwd_text = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtGeneratedPassword"));
Console.WriteLine(driver.ExecuteJavaScript<String>("return 
arguments[0].textContent", passwd_text));
```

but nothing is displayed

Comment: html5 code:                                                                                                               
<input id="txtGeneratedPassword" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: overridePassword, enable: false" title="" disabled="">

Comment: did u try to get password just by using selenium method passwd_text.Text?

Comment: Rather than showing us the knockout view of the world, please view the DOM using Chrome Developer Tools and show us the runtime HTML when the Selenium code is running.

Comment: @JeffHuang you want get value attribute `data-bind` ?

Comment: Yes, I want get value attribute data-bind

Answer (score 0):

you want to get the value, not the text:
[How can one get the value of a text input using Selenium with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121302/how-can-one-get-the-value-of-a-text-input-using-selenium-with-c)

```
passwd_text.GetAttribute("value")
```

Comment: Does not work. Please note that “enable : false” in html. It is hiding and will get nothing

Comment: Show more of the HTML.